# Python gst segmentation fault

Tags: python, pygtk, gstreamer

I want to create a player class to play music with gst. This ist the code:

```
from gi.repository import GObject
GObject.threads_init()
import gst

class PlayerControl:
    def __init__(self, main_window):

        self.player = gst.element_factory_make("playbin2", "player")
        self.sink = gst.element_factory_make("autoaudiosink", "player Output")
        self.videosink= gst.element_factory_make("fakesink", "player fake Output")
        self.player.set_property("video-sink", self.videosink)
        self.player.set_property("audio-sink", self.sink)
        self.player_bus = self.player.get_bus()
        self.player_bus.add_signal_watch()
        self.player_bus.connect("message", self.on_messages)
        self.player.connect("about-to-finish", self.on_finish)
        self.main_window = main_window
        self.main_window.seek_bar.connect("value-changed", self.on_slider_changed)
        self.main_window.seek_bar.set_range(0, 100)
        self.playing = False

    def on_messages(self, bus, message):
        print(message)


    def play(self, file):
        self.playing = True
        self.player.set_state(gst.STATE_READY)
        self.player.set_property("uri", "file:///"+str(file)) # örnek olsun diye
        self.player.set_state(gst.STATE_PLAYING)
        GObject.timeout_add(100, self.update_slider)
    [...]
```

I'm calling this from another class like this to play sound:

```
from file import PlayerControl
class PlayerExample():
    def __init__( self ):
    self.player_gst = PlayerControl(self)
    [...]
    def play(self, file):
        self.playing = True
        self.player.set_state(gst.STATE_READY)
        self.player.set_property("uri", "file:///"+str(file))
        self.player.set_state(gst.STATE_PLAYING)
        GObject.timeout_add(100, self.update_slider)
    [...]
```

I've connected a gtk button to play function. When i clicked the button i take `segmentation fault` without any information. 
Also if i remove `self.player_bus.add_signal_watch()` and `self.player.connect("about-to-finish", self.on_finish)` lines from my PlayerControl class, it works and play sound but i need to call on_finished function with "about-to-finish" signal.
Why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GObject.threads_init()` from gi.repository doesn't work with pygst "0.10"
you need to add:

```
import gobject
gobject.threads_init()
import gst
```

top of the player class.
Or use Gst-1.0 https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Novacut/GStreamer1.0